# Battery status always at 100% and a second status in settings with correct level

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery, ideapad

I've just switched from Windows 11 to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and I love it.

I'm learning a lot about Linux and fixed some problems, but there's one I can't find the issue.

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 330-15IKB.

The battery level on the upper status bar is always 100%, but when I look at the power settings, the battery section shows me a first line with fully charged battery and a second line with the real battery level marked "Extra".

[image: https://vision-tpl.com/shares/Screenshot_2022-10-21.png]

I have only one battery on this laptop.
I've discovered that the main battery showed is in fact my UPS battery backup who is plugged via USB for it's management software I had in Windows. If I unplugged it, my laptop battery level shows up correctly.

My question is... how to show the actual laptop battery first and the UPS as an extra?

Comment: Not sure about this. I have two battery indicators on my Lenovo thinkpad even when I'm not charging.  As an experiment, I left my laptop on until it drained. First the battery went to 0% then the Extra went to 2% and automatically paused the machine. Now that I've plugged the charging adapter in, the Main keeps increasing while the Extra remains at 2%